# IAM role condition not applying

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to assign the "CLOUD SQL EDITOR" role to a specific database, specifically my preprod database, however it doesn't work. Whatever I try, it either allows access to all the other databases, or doesn't allow access to any database.

Here is what my condition looks like:

```
resource.name.startsWith('projects/test-project123/instances/preprod-mysql')
```

The other databases I have are the following:
dev-mysql
qa-mysql

I specifically want the user to be granted the role to the preprod-mysql database.

I have also tried the following command:

```
resource.name.endsWith('preprod-mysql')
```

None of them work...

Comment: IAM conditions do not apply to databases. You must grant database level permissions at the database itself and not via IAM. I mean using SQL commands similar to **grant select on TABLE_NAME to USERNAME`.

Comment: @JohnHanley, yes but if the user is granted SQL EDITOR role, then goes to the console and deletes the production database (or changes it in a bad way) from the gcp console, how do you prevent that?

Comment: Don't give them the role to do so. Grant the user only the permissions required at the correct location. There are separate permissions for the database server and the databases.

Comment: @JohnHanley, but the user requires full access to the non-production database from both the GCP console and via mysql, the mysql part is fine, but I can't figure out the GCP part because it's located in the same project as the production database.

Comment: Create a new project and move the non-production database out of the production project.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to assign the "CLOUD SQL EDITOR" role to a specific database, specifically my preprod database, however it doesn't work. Whatever I try, it either allows access to all the other databases, or doesn't allow access to any database.

> ... if the user is granted SQL EDITOR role, then goes to the console and deletes the production database (or changes it in a bad way) from the gcp console, how do you prevent that?

> ... the user requires full access to the non-production database

As @JohnHanley suggested: Create a new project and move the non-production database out of the production project. Then grant the user only the permissions required at the new project.